# Prove (using convergence definition) that the limit of $x_{n}=\frac{n+(-1)^{n}}{n+1}$ is equal to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Prove that the limit of $x_{n}=\frac{n+(-1)^{n}}{n+1}$ is equal to $0$

**My attempt**

I have to prove that

For any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_{n}-a|<\epsilon, \quad\forall n\geq N$.

Replacing: $|\frac{n+(-1)^{n}}{n+1}|<\epsilon \quad\forall n\geq N$.

$|\frac{n+1-1+(-1)^{n}}{n+1}|<\epsilon \rightarrow |1 +\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{n+1}|<\epsilon $.

Then we know that $ \frac{-2}{n+1} \leq  \frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{n+1}$ is always true, so

$ \frac{-2}{N+1} <\epsilon \rightarrow N>\frac{-2}{\epsilon}-1$

So, finally $N=\left \lfloor \frac{-2}{\epsilon}\right \rfloor$ is the N that I was looking for.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+(-1)^{n}}{n+1}=1$

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: With the premise that the limit is $0$, your proof cannot be right, and is indeed not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|x_n-1|=\frac{|-1+(-1)^n|}{n+1}.$$

The numerator is at most $2$ so that

$$n>N=\frac2\epsilon\implies |x_n-1|<\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 4):

This is not correct.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 1$$

Clearly

$$1 - \frac{2}{n+1} = \frac{n-1}{n+1} \le x_n \le \frac{n+1}{n+1} = 1$$

and both the left and right side of those converge to $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

---

**Using $\epsilon$:**

If $N > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$, then for $n+1 > N$, using the above,

$$1  \ge x_n \ge  1 - \frac{2}{n+1} > 1 - \frac{2}{N} > 1 - \epsilon$$

Thus for any $n > N-1$,

$$1 - \epsilon < x_n \le 1 \implies -\epsilon < x _n- 1 \le 0 < \epsilon$$

Therefore $|x_n - 1| < \epsilon$, which means the limit is indeed $1$.

Comment: This is right, of course, but OP asked for an answer based on the definition of convergence. So he probably wants epsilons in the answer.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I've edited in some $\epsilon$'s.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made a mistake, the actual limit is 1 as you said.

Answer (score 1):

To show that,
if
$x_{n}
=\frac{n+(-1)^{n}}{n+1}
$,
then
$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 1
$
(not $0$ as stated):

$x_{n}-1
=\frac{n+(-1)^{n}}{n+1}-1
=\frac{n+(-1)^{n}-(n+1)}{n+1}
=\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{n+1}
$
so
$|x_{n}-1|
=|\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{n+1}|
=\frac{|(-1)^{n}-1|}{n+1}
\le\frac{2}{n+1}
$
since
$-2 \le (-1)^{n}-1 \le 0$.

Therefore,
to make
$|x_{n}-1|
\le \epsilon
$,
it is sufficient to make
$\frac{2}{n+1}
\le \epsilon
$
or
$n \ge \frac{2}{\epsilon}-1
$.